# Unable to get id from TableView in Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I attached some eventListeners to a number of elements, like this:

```
$.someButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { eventHandling(evt); });
$.someImageView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { eventHandling(evt); });
$.someWindow.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { eventHandling(evt); });
$.someTableView.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { eventHandling(evt); });
```

Then, I catch them like this:

```
function eventHandling(evt) {
    switch (evt.source.id) {
        case "someButton":
            console.log("button clicked");
            break;

        case "someImageView":
            console.log("imageview clicked");
            break;

        case "someWindow":
            console.log("window clicked");
            break;

        case "someTableView":
            console.log("tableview clicked");
            break;

    };
};
```

They all log their id's, except the TableView which logs *undefined*.
The TableView is set like this (minimised):

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="main">
        <TableView bottom="100" zIndex="0" id="someTableView" dataCollection="inspection" dataFilter="statusFilter">
            ...
        </TableView>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 3):

To tell you more clearly on why this error is happening, we need more UI/XML code to know how TableView is linked with other UI elements.

The only guess right now is that any of the TableView Row's child element(s) can also fire that click event. Can you also share the code where you are getting **undefined printed on console** ?

Apart from this, I observe a less useful code pattern here - **Why are you using *switch* statement just to know the id of clicked element?**

I would prefer to use below code instead of above code.

```
$.someButton.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
$.someImageView.addEventListener('click', imageViewClick);
$.someWindow.addEventListener('click', windowClick);
$.someTableView.addEventListener('click', tableClick);


function buttonClick(e) {
   // ..... 
}

function windowClick(e) {
   // ..... 
}

function imageViewClick(e) {
   // ..... 
}

function tableClick(e) {
   // ..... 
}
```

The point here is that running the code by assuming the id of source-view which fired that event is not a good-idea, because your layout might change in future or you can rename the IDs of those elements or could be any other reason.

Comment: Agree to what Prashant has mentioned, Also adding to it, the id to action mapping overhead is removed by directly registering the click listeners.

Comment: Thanks, updated my code according to Prashant's suggestion